# Blocking animated gifs in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, animation

I am trying to block animated gifts in Safari.

I installed Deanimator, but it is dated and it does not always work.

I also searched for Saft, but it seems this extension was abandoned.

Does anyone knows an alternative way of doing it?

Comment: Do you want them to stop being animated, or do you not want to display gifs at all?

Comment: @moneyt I would prefer stopping animations *and* still display gifs

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to install and use a local filtering proxy:

The venerable [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org) will allow you to deanimate GIFs.

While a fine grained setup can be quite involved, that deanimated GIF-thing is quite easy to configure with the preset "medium" already. (Or via one radio button in the settings page.)

Playing those GIFs in a website you *do* want to see is then quite a hassle, though. That would require a trip to System Preferences, change proxy settings and then reloading the page. Depending on how often you need that feature, it's easiest to use another browser for that that does not get filtered.

As two examples: [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/) comes to mind, since it has proxy settings differing from the system preferences, or [OmniWeb](https://www.omnigroup.com/more), which ignores the system settings.

Comment: actually with Firefox is quite easy stopping animations with settings. I still use a lot Safari. I would prefer a solution at browser level, nonetheless this can be a way to go.